# I am getting ! LaTeX Error: Command \beamer@@tmpop@page number in head/foot@default already defined error

Tags: beamer, errors

I have tried all the answers of this question previously asked. I ain't able to generate `ppt` still
Even the small code like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Hello
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

is not running and giving the error. I am using Miktex 2.9 and I have installed and updated almost all the packages.

log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/Vigya/Documents/reports/check.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.15> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamer.cls
Document Class: beamer 2018/01/27 v3.49 A class for typesetting presentations

(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasemodes.sty
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty")
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasedecode.st
y)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseoptions.s
ty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size11.clo")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-latex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ms\everyshi.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgf.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def
")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.t
ex")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometr
ic.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code
.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarit
hmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.c
ode.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.co
de.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations
.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex"
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.te
x")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex"
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.te
x"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.t
ex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.co
de.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.t
ex"))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\xxcolor.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\atbegshi.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty")

Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"))
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaserequires.
sty
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasecompatibi
lity.sty)
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasefont.sty
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\sansmathaccent\sansmathaccent.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\filehook\filehook.sty")))
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetranslato
r.sty
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\translator\translator.sty)
)
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasemisc.sty)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetwoscreens.sty")
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseoverlay.s
ty) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetitle.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasesection.sty")
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseframe.sty
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseverbatim.sty")
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseframesize
.sty)
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseframecomp
onents.sty)
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasecolor.sty
)
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasenotes.sty
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetoc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetemplates.sty"
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseauxtempla
tes.sty
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseboxes.sty
)))
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaselocalstru
cture.sty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\enumerate.sty"))
(C:\Users\Vigya\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasenavigatio
n.sty) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetheorems.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amscls\amsthm.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasethemes.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerthemedefault.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerfontthemedefault.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamercolorthemedefault.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerinnerthemedefault.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerouterthemedefault.sty"

! LaTeX Error: Command \beamer@@tmpop@page number in head/foot@default already 
defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.100
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Beamer results in pdf, not ppt! Did you compile with `pdflatex mwe.tex`?

Comment: yes I did; but i am still getting the error

Comment: Have you updated your miktex recently? Admin update _and_ user update. We can see from the log that your document uses resources from the Amin installation and from User updates (the `Roaming` lines). These might not have the same versions

Comment: on opening Miktex Update, I had updated the packages; do i need to do anything more?   On opening Miktex Update(Admin)., I am getting Windows API index 87, error

Comment: That sounds like you have not updated miktex in a long time. MikTeX does not use `MikTeX Update (Admin)` anymore. It uses the MikTeX console (one programme instead of many)

Comment: It might be a good idea to just use a complete fresh install of MikTeX

Comment: your version 2.9.6500  current =2.9.6980+

Comment: ok, should I remove miktex completely; and then reinstall it using one of the downloaded files from the website?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments